# Re-wiring switched box to pass through

Tags: electrical, switch

I'm dealing with a two-gang electrical box that currently houses two switches. The one on the left controls a bare bulb that I'd like to eliminate, while the other switch has been stuck in the "on" position with a little plastic piece ever since we moved in. It's responsible for operating the garage door openers, and maybe some other stuff (I'm not entirely sure).

My goal here is to transform this setup into a splice/junction box.

[image: before pic]

Now, focusing on the switch on the right, which was always in the "on" position, you'll notice there's a 14/3 cable connected to it with black and red wires. I attempted a simple solution by connecting all wires of the same color together and capping the red one. Clearly, that didn't work since my garage doors aren't functioning anymore. Can anyone help me figure out what went wrong?

[image: old-switches]

[image: re-wire-switch-1]

[image: red-wire-switch-2]

[image: after-wrong]

Answer (score 2):

After considering for a while, I simply attached the red to the blacks and everything worked.

Comment: Looking at the wiring in the outlet in the ceiling where the GDO plugs in should have told you this.